# how can I use a switch statement with only one print line for java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

How can I print something inside of a case without having several system.out.print in each case so that I can only use one single system.out.print for the whole program?

```
      int example;
      String newE;
      switch (number)
      {
         case 1:
         statement;
         break;
         case 2:
         statement;
         break;
  } 
  System.out.println(statmenr);
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to print? You can simply assign a string to a variable that you print at the end.

Comment: You should really explain more what you want to achieve. If you just want to print out the statement number then it's same as the number you use as an argument for switch.

Comment: please explain what statement should be.

Answer (score 1):

You would assign the statement you want to print to a variable inside the switch, and then print the contents of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the desired output to `newE` and print that. Also, your `number` appears to be named `example`. I would suggest you also add a `default` case for when your value isn't `1` or `2`. Something like

```
int example = 1; // <-- some value
String newE;
switch (example)
{
case 1:
    newE = "case 1";
    break;
case 2:
    newE = "case 2";
    break;
default:
    newE = "not case 1 or case 2";
} 
System.out.println(newE);
```